# smashing stack detected program terminated in c

Tags: c, linux

I am getting this error *****smashing stack detected******program terminated .I am not using any buffer.Just reading record by record.Please help me.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct art
{
    char name[30];
    float velocity;
    float min_angle;
    float max_angle;
};
create(char *,float,float,float); */
int main()
{

    // printf("I am starting"); 

    FILE *infile;
    struct art input;

    /*** open the accounts file ***/
    infile = fopen ("artillery.txt","r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening artillery.txt\n\n");
         // exit (1);
    }

    while (fread (&input, sizeof(struct art), 6, infile))
    { 
        printf("%s", input.name);
        printf("%f", input.velocity);
        printf("%f", input.min_angle);
        printf("%f", input.max_angle);              
    }
    return 0;
}
```

file records are:

```
canon 1700 30 45
bazooka 80 30 45
tank 2000 33 50
ak-47 715 0 90
pistol9mm 380 0 90
revolver 400 0 90
```

Comment: @iharob    i declared any array of 5(0-5) 6 records but it shows garbage after displaying the records.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With this

```
fread (&input, sizeof(struct art), 6, infile)
```

you are trying to read 6 records into a variable which is a single struct. To read 6 records, you would need an array of 6 structs

```
struct art input[6];
```

But you are reading from a text file anyway, so you cannot read directly into the struct.

Comment: ...but the data is text and needs to be converted into the floats, so this won't work either.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I thought I mentioned that.

Comment: @PaulOglivie did you downvote and then post your own answer?

Comment: he approves your answer so he will now probably declare an array of 6 structs and tries to read that. I looked over your last note too.

Comment: @PaulOglivie I would say it is bad form to downvote other answers.

Comment: I would have downvoted also without posting an answer myself because you don't give a solution, even though I respect most of your answers (and upvoted them) very much.

Comment: @PaulOglivie sadly I cannot delete this answer, but OP did ask why the stack is breaking, which I have expalained.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading text data as if it was binary. You can't read the text in the file with a structure like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fgets` to read the file line-by-line. Then convert each line into the struct. You could use `strtok` to break on the space and use `atof` to convert the numbers into floats.